# What is the most space-efficient propellant for a rocket ship?

Tags: hard-science

What propellant would give the best total impulse to volume ratio? The rocket engine can be anything that could realistically work. The propellant volume should include the tanks that store the propellant, and the mechanisms that bring it to the engine. The ship has a powerful nuclear reactor to provide energy, but if the engine your answer proposes needs an additional fuel, include its volume in the calculation

Comment: Have you read *Rocket Ship Galileo*?

Comment: Because of the lack of air resistance in space, and the [tyranny of the rocket equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation) most rockets are far more concerned with mass than they are with volume. Every change in mass will greatly affect Δv while assuming mass stays constant a volumetric change will have exactly 0 impact. Can you explain why you're concerned with the most volumetrically efficient engine?

Comment: I think it depends on how much energy your nuclear reactor can produce and how much total impulse you want. If energy isn't a concern at all, then I'm pretty sure the most efficient propellant is light.

Comment: Another important question is, are you concerned about atmospheric flight (in addition to vacuum flight)? I'm guessing that atmospheric flight is a concern here, since volume doesn't really matter once you get out of the atmosphere.

Comment: Define 'propellant'. Is it strictly 'reaction mass'? Or does it have to be something that provides the energy for being propelled? Chemical propellants provide the energy AND the reaction mass, ion engines only provide the reaction mass.

Comment: @ 
Zeiss Ikon
  Rocket Ship Galileo was the first Sci Fi novel I read,and I loved it!!!!!  The type of story any boy would love!!

Comment: Heinlein used zinc in *Galileo* because it's dense (close to iron) and melts/boils at accessible temperatures, so could provide its own ejection force.

Answer (score 4):

## Metallic Osmium

Without going into exotic forms of matter (which the hard science tag would prohibit), what you really need is the highest density material you can find. This is elemental osmium as it has a density of 22.61 g/cm^3 which is higher than any other material found on earth.

Since you are using nuclear energy, all you really need is called "Reaction Mass" and so the most volume efficient way to store that reaction mass is the most dense material possible, which is Osmium.

Notes on other materials

1. Iridium, can be more dense than osmium at high pressures, but not by a lot, and when you consider the additional equipment needed to keep the pressure high, the osmium is still better.
2. Hassium and Meitnerium: It is predicted that hassium and meitnerium could have much higher densities, however those elements have half lives measured in seconds, so it would not be practical for rocketry.
3. Compressed gasses/plasma: For most phase diagrams, the increased pressure will force the gas to become solid, at which point you would probably be better off trying to compress your solid Osmium, or Iridium.

Comment: On the practical side, however, your "solid" osmium (/iridium/platinum alloy, since these metals are very difficult to fully separate) would just be a permanent lump.  If it's powdered, so you can treat it as a fluid, you give up so much density you might be ahead with mercury, and if you plan to melt it, there's the whole "in what" question, since only tungsten is solid at their melting point, and not for long above it.

Comment: I wonder if you can make interstitial alloys of these elements. They're far enough down the periodic table for it to be plausible. It'd boost density a little.

Answer (score 2):

**Waste.**

You could store tightly packed stuff to use as reaction mass, as with the osmium suggestion.  Ultimately that is stuff you have brought with for a purpose and it occupies space.

If you have stuff on board with no purpose (or which no longer has a purpose), you can use that as reaction mass.  That requires negative volume to store because you free up volume when you get rid of it.
For example: you have a nuclear reactor.  Whether fission or fusion this will produce waste.  That waste can be used as reaction mass.  You want to be rid of it and might as well get some use out of it.

If you are on an efficiently recycling colony ship you might recycle biological waste and so it would not be available for propulsion.  If you are on a warship that sort of recycling is more trouble than it is worth, and you can use biowastes as propulsion mass.

Also re biowastes - when you use your propulsion device as a weapon it sends a certain message to your enemy when they realize what they are being pelted with.

Apropos finding things to throw into the ion drive:
https://www.fictionpress.com/s/3362047/1/Platinum-flames